# Mostrar todos los resultados de una regla en Prolog

Tags: array, prolog, concatenación

Quisiera saber si hay una manera de mostrar todas las salidas cuando se hace una consulta en Prolog de una regla, me explico.
Teniendo las reglas

```
padres(david,jose).
padres(david,martin).
padres(hector,mariana).
```

cuando se crea una regla donde se pregunta cuales son los hijos de esos padres ejemplo

```
espadre(A):- padres(A,X),display(X).
```

el resultado de la siguiente regla en caso de ser David son las siguientes

```
   ?-espadre(david).
//jose;
//martin
```

estos serian los resultados que arrojaria prolog, pero estos no despliegan todo, solo arroja "Jose" al menos que se le de enter, visualisaria "martin"

Quisiera hacer que con una regla, me muestre todos sus resultados posibles que tenga, sea 1 o 20 que cumplan, ya sea que esten dentro de un arreglo , o seguidos

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al menos en swi-prolog el predicado se llama `bagof/3` y su sintaxis se eplica de la siguiente manera:

```
bagof(UnaVariable, tupredicado(UnaVariable,LoQueSea, EnSerioLoQueSea, YCuantosSean), UnasVariables)
```

Y como te imaginarás, todo se almacenará en una lista que es la parte de `UnasVariables`, mientras que `UnaVariable` será la variable que usará para consultar todos los posibles resultados.

```
?- bagof(Padre,espadre(Padre),Padres).
```

> josemartinmariana
>
> Padres = [david, david, hector].

Como verás en el resultado de consola salen otros nombres y es debido a que tienes `display(X)`

### Enlaces

[Documentación oficial](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3)